# plot martingal and shoenfeld residuals with SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to check the linearity assumption of my covariates as well as the PH assumption. Knowing that all my covariates are time varying (the value can change many times during the follow up).
But this code did not work with the counting process neither the programming statement code in SAS

```
ODS GRAPHICS ON;
proc phreg data=data1;
Model(start,stop)*event(0)=x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6;
assess var=(x1 x2 )/resample;
run;
ODS GRAPHICS Off;
```

Is there any other way to plot martingal and shoenfeld residuals in a cox model with time varying covariates?
Thank you in advance.